# Should I use Provider instead of Notifier with void in Riverpod

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have been using `Notifier` with `void` type for the state. I am wondering is this the recommended way to use notifier or should I just use the normal `Provider`? I used this just to access some function.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve this way?

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to use a `Notifier` with type `void`. It is assumed that:

- `Provider` for a simple state that we cannot change externally
- `StateProvider` is also for a simple state, but which we can change externally
- `(Async)NotifierProvider` for complex state when you need to have methods to manage it

But one way or another, some state must be stored in each of the providers. That's the point of it) If there is no state - maybe it's just a utility class or a repository

Verdict: it makes no sense to use providers with void type state.

Comment: Ya, I think you are right. But I got this idea because of this article https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-riverpod-async-notifier/#how-does-asyncnotifier-work. I think this only make sense for AsyncNotifier to present loading and error state

Comment: So I currently use provider and pass ref to the class constructor if the class need ref to work.

Comment: Yes, in that case it's semantically correct to use `Provider` and pass the reference to `ref`, although it's boylerplayer. Because there is no state as such, and `Provder` simply stores an instance of the class

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is a `Provider` or a `Notifier`, neither should return `void`.

Returning `void` is generally a sign that something is going wrong. There are *some* use-cases (such as when returning a `Stream<void>` for periodic refresh of another provider). But generally, you do not want to do so.

From my experience, most people trying to return `void` in a provider only do so because they have split their app into too many small chunks.

A `Notifier` is meant to be a full CRUD.

You'd meant to do:

```dart
class UserNotifier extends AsyncNotifier<User> {
  @override
  Future<User> build() => http.get('/user');

  setUser(User user) => http.post('/user', user.toJson());

  deleteUser(String userId) => http.delete('/user', userId);
}
```

Returning `void` in `build` means that chances are your `http.get` is placed in a different provider.